# Add HTML to skadate sidebar

Tags: smarty

Can someone explain how exactly to add some html to the sidebar of a template in Skadate?  It is using smarty templates and I am trying a lot of different ways but have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

It is located in Layout -> Components -> Page_Sidebar -> Default.tpl.  Be sure to also clear the site cache in the admin panel after making changes.  I missed that and that is why none of my changes were showing up.